# Samsung Gear VR - some sounds files fail to play in android device

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, oculus, virtual-reality

I am trying add some music to my game , they work fine in play mode

but in my Gear VR thats run by android device some of those file  doesn't work

all files are MP3 that supported by android .

I play my music file on wake

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? They don't play at all? They sound weird?..

Comment: they dont work at all